# What does "sleeps" mean in holiday cottage/appartment descriptions?

Tags: bookings, accommodation, guidebooks

I am searching for accommodation.

And I found many "sleeps" options. Does that mean the number of beds?

[image]

This is another example:

[image]

Comment: this looks like a "self catering" type accomodation description, where you rent a whole property for your group, not a hostel. A "hostel" is a place where you rent beds in a room shared with some number of others, who may not be part of your group. Do you really mean hostel?

Answer (score 21):

It's usually a number for  how many people the place can accommodate. It's NOT always an indication of the number of beds.

([Dictionary defintion - number 7 in this case](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sleep)):

> to accommodate for sleeping; have sleeping accommodations for

For example, a 2 bedroom apartment I'm staying in during August sleeps arguably 8, but only has 4 beds - a double, a queen, and two single bunks. It also has a sleeper couch.  So in theory you could fill all those and get 8, but depending on your group, some may not want to sleep in the same bed as someone else, or might not like a couch.

So essentially, it's a theoretical maximum number of people who can sleep there, but in reality, it'll depend on the parameters of the group you have staying there.

In your first example, it indicates there are 4 bedrooms, and sleeps 10. I'd guess at either 4 double beds in total, plus a sleeper couch or cot, but it might also be 8 single beds (2 in each bedroom) plus two couches. You usually need to check more details on the listing to confirm.

In the second example,a studio that sleeps two is almost always a queen/double bed or a sleeper couch that folds out into a bed.  Great for a couple, but not ideal for say, two business colleagues, or friends who are not in a relationship and don't want to share a bed.

Comment: thanks you for answer, please how can i know the number of beds? we are two not in relationship, so we are just friends, it is written this (Studio 1 BA Sleeps 2) i need two beds but each bed is single. sorry for my english

Comment: @sarahsarah there's no way to know from that description.  You'll need to read more of the listing to see if it describes it, or if there are photos.  Or contact the company/poster of the listing. Your English is fine :)

Comment: As you need two single beds, twins (which are two single beds each on the floor) or bunks (two beds, one above the other) is what to look for. Or an accommodation that sleeps at least three, as beds never sleep more than 2 unless mentioned as such.